# If the Islamic prophet considered Jesus to be a prophet, why did he teach holy war and live by the sword?

Tags: violence

Jesus taught pacifism both in his teaching and by example:

> King James Bible Matthew 26:52 Then said Jesus unto him, Put up again
>   thy sword into his place: for all they that take the sword shall
>   perish with the sword.
>
> Matthew 5: 38You have heard that it was said, ‘Eye for eye and tooth
>   for tooth.’ 39But I tell you not to resist an evil person. If someone
>   slaps you on your right cheek, turn to him the other also; 40if
>   someone wants to sue you and take your tunic, let him have your cloak
>   as well;
>
> John 18:36 NET Bible Jesus replied, "My kingdom is not from this
>   world. If my kingdom were from this world, my servants would be
>   fighting to keep me from being handed over to the Jewish authorities.
>   But as it is, my kingdom is not from here."

If Jesus was regarded by the Islamic prophet as a true prophet, why didn't he obey him? Why did he contradict him and do the very opposite of what he taught?

Comment: The same could be asked as to why Jesus taught the opposite of what was revealed to Moses in the Torah and the stance of the rest of the Tanakh, weren't the Jews expecting a warrior-king Messiah? Muslims don't consider the gospels to be authentic, so the question is moot.

Comment: So which Jesus is considered a true prophet, if not the one in the gospels? Was there a violent Jesus in some other document?

Comment: No idea why this is downvoted?? People need to understand what the downvote button is for. This is a good question! Needs to be upvoted regardless of if you agree with the message or not.

Answer (score 8):

There are some verses which give us a different idea. Comments like "sell your cloak and buy a sword" and "I did not come to bring peace" are not entirely pacifistic comments; and one of his close companions was Simon who was a revolutionary zealot!!

That aside, even if we assume that Jesus was anti-war and a pacifist, this was only for the time period that he was in and the people of his nation specifically. [Remember he allegedly said, "He answered, "I was sent only to the lost sheep of Israel" - Matthew 15:24]. This is not binding upon the rest of humanity of all eras, to whom he was not sent.

Jesus' law became abrogated by the Qur'an. Just as the OT's commands to war became abrogated by the NT's message of non-violence [which you Christians acknowledge], so too did the NT's message of non-violence become abrogated by the Qur'an permitting physical fighting when needed.

*@"If Jesus was regarded by the Islamic prophet as a true prophet, why didn't he obey him? Why did he contradict him and do the very opposite of what he taught?"*

^^ This was no more "disobedience" than Jesus' stance was disobedience of Moses. All Prophets, even if they came with different laws, supported each other. Jesus did not "look down" on Moses for overseeing the fighting of the Israelites. And Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) did not "look down" on Jesus for not fighting when oppression was occurring in his time period.

Each was commanded by God to respond differently. They all acted righteously and correctly.